# Matrices in SU(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}\in SU(2)$. we have $M\overline M^t= \begin{bmatrix}
aa^*+cc^* & ab^*+cd^* \\
ba^*+dc^* & bb^*+dd^*
\end{bmatrix}$, and we must have $M\overline M^t=I $.

I wonder how to for these four quadratic equations to get $c=-\overline b$ and $d=\overline a$.

So far I am only able to conclude $a,d$ and $b,c $ have the same magnitudes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a\end{pmatrix}.$$Imposing $ad-bc=1$ and setting this equal to $$\begin{pmatrix} \overline{a} & \overline{c} \\ \overline{b} & \overline{d}\end{pmatrix}$$gives the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot the condition $\det=1$. This implies that the inverse of your matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}$$ Since that must be equal to $A^T$, you get that this is equal to
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar a  & \bar c  \\
\bar b & \bar d
\end{bmatrix}

So $a=\bar d, \bar c=-b, \bar b=-c$.